# EF mapping one to one optional

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have som mapping problem with EF.

This is my classes

```
public class User{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // Fullname of the user account owner
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine, but now I want to create the navigation property Player and User in this classes. I have this Fluent code:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.Player)
            .WithOptionalDependent(x => x.User)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("Username"));
```

But I only get this error message, and I have no ide what's wrong.

*Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'Username'
was already defined.*

My DB setup looks like the classes, in the player table the Name is unique. It's not unique in the User table. A user can exist without a player and vice versa. (Actully I don't want any User property inside the Player class but I think it's a requierment?!)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's complaining about the fact that UserName is already a property in the object model. See the docs for the Map() method:

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.foreignkeynavigationpropertyconfiguration.map%28v=vs.103%29:

> Configures the relationship to use foreign key property(s) **that are
>   not exposed in the object model.** The column(s) and table can be
>   customized by specifying a configuration action. If an empty
>   configuration action is specified then column name(s) will be
>   generated by convention. If foreign key properties are exposed in the
>   object model then use the HasForeignKey method. Not all relationships
>   support exposing foreign key properties in the object model.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the modelBuilder code and mark the PrimaryKey as a ForeignKey on the dependent table. For example if Players don't exist without a User:

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // Fullname of the user account owner
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The ForeignKey attribute tells EF which side of the one-to-one is dependent, allowing it to map it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If your columns in the database has the same name as the properties of your model you don't need to map the property ".Map(x => x.MapKey("Username"));" EF already mapped the property "Username" using the convention and is because of that the EF is complaining

Answer (score 0):

With your entities

...I just like to do it the other way around:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.User)
    .WithRequiredDependent(i => i.Player);
```

or this (optional):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
    .HasRequired(i => i.User)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Player);
```